# Executing bash command within a python script called from crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I am writing a python script, I want to call from crontab. It script calls the `xrandr` command and saves its output in a variable like so:
`output = subprocess.run('xrandr', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')`

I want the output of `xrandr` to be saved in a string.
This works all fine if I execute it from terminal, but if I run it using cron, the variable `output` stays empty.
the rest of the code is executed normally, so cron isn't the problem.
So how can I make this command execute properly?
thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store output, you can use `communicate()` here to help out, so like this:

```
from subprocess import PIPE
output = subprocess.run('xrandr', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
text = output.communicate()[0]
print(text)
```

OR maybe this, in that case you can remove the `.stdout.decode('utf-8')` not too sure but it give a shot with and without it:

```
from subprocess import PIPE
output = subprocess.run('xrandr', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(output.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in cron environment the PATH variable is not set, so you should provide absolute path to xrandr (you can find it by `which xrandr`).
E.g. if this path `/usr/bin/xrandr` try

```py
from subprocess import PIPE
output = subprocess.run('/usr/bin/xrandr', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
text = output.communicate()[0]
print(text)
```

The better way for my opinion is to capture stderr as well and log error when it occures.

Comment: The problem is bigger than that. If I put /usr/bin/xrandr directly into my crontab, and redirect the output to a file, it doesn't do anything. I found out that the DISPLAY variable is not set in cron, but I dint manage to set it. So if one of you knows how, it would be very much appreciated.